# Error con resultado en símbolo del sistema

Tags: java

estoy intentando mejorar mi lógica de programación con java y estoy haciendo una serie de ejercicios, para este caso debo resolver el siguiente:

Escribir un programa que muestre por pantalla el resultado de la siguiente operación aritmética ((3+2)/(2*5))^2, estoy realizando las ejecuciones desde el símbolo del sistema pero no me arroja el resultado correcto que es 0.25, me arroja 0.0.

¿Qué puede estar pasando con este resultado?, este es el código que escribí:

```
public class Operacion{
  public static void main(String args[]){

   double operacion = ((3+2)/(2*5));
   int potencia = 2;
   
   double resultado = Math.pow(operacion, potencia);

   System.out.println("El resultado de la operaición es: " + resultado);
 }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Un saludo.

Comment: Dada la gran respuesta de jachguate, solo puedo agregar un comentario, los paréntesis externos están de más.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la línea

```
double operacion = ((3+2)/(2*5));
```

Aunque estás almacenando el resultado de la operación en una variable de coma flotante de tipo `double`, dado que solamente das números enteros en la expresión `((3+2)/(2*5))`, el compilador realiza la división entera, es decir, termina haciendo la división entera `5/10`, que da como resultado un cociente 0 (entero).

Este resultado, que se obtiene sin voltear a ver dónde se va a almacenar o para que se va a utilizar, luego es *promovido* a un valor de coma flotante para poder ser almacenado en la variable `operacion`.

Para que el sistema haga las operaciones de entrada con números de coma flotante al evaluar la expresión, agrega el punto decimal a los números, puedes hacerlo con todos para mayor claridad:

```
double operacion = ((3.0+2.0)/(2.0*5.0));
```

Aunque basta con que lo hagas con un número del dividendo:

```
double operacion = ((3.0+2)/(2*5));
```

Con ese cambio, obtendrás el valor de 0.25 que esperas ver en la salida.

Comment: Entendido, gracias por tu valiosa respuesta.

Comment: Si esta respuesta ha sido la que te ha ayudado a resolver el problema, te invito a marcarla como aceptada, pues eso informará a futuros visitantes. Encontrarás más información en [qué hacer si me responden](/help/someone-answers). Si no recuerdas bien como funcionamos por aquí, puedes hacer de nuevo el [tour].